# Looking for an English counting idiom

Tags: idioms

How does one say in English, “to make a stroke” (when counting objects)? The classic example is when you “make a stroke” for each year you've spent in prison. (I think that's called “fences”?)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of four lines, crossed by a fifth? ( I understood that to be counting days, rather than years.) Like this: [https://www.shutterstock.com/search/prison+wall].

Comment: 'tallying', 'notching', 'marking' (as in 'marking time'), 'ticking', 'scoring' also 'counting off', 'ticking off' and various other combinations (but not 'stroking off', although 'striking off' might be usable).

Comment: What @Lee said. [*Sean had made a calendar which he kept rolled up at the bottom of his school bag. Every morning he marked off another square. People in prison **ticked off** the days like that, scratching a line on the walls of their cell.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22People+in+prison+ticked+off%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% if I understand you correctly, but the verb that comes to my mind is *[to tally](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tally?s=t)*, such as *he tallied each day that he was in prison*. This sounds a bit British to me, but I'm sure most English speakers would understand it (for the record, I'm American). You could also use the word *record*, as in *he recorded each day he was in prison*, but this sound a bit more vague. *Stroke* is understandable in this context, but it sounds a bit weird to the ear.

I have no idea what you mean by **fences**.

Comment: @nmg49 The tallies referred to in my comment to the OP look a bit like fences, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, I would use _tally_ as a Brit.

Comment: In the UK at least, it's common when counting in this way to make every fifth mark across the previous four, to make adding up the total easier. This is called a five-barred gate. Perhaps this is what the questioner meant by 'fences'?